# Message shows up while building the .pip project

Tags: ocean

The following message shows up while building my .pip project. Which file is the system not able to find?
------ Build started: Project: PIP_SWIFT, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
The system cannot find the file specified.
  Deploy list file copier - command line tool.
  Version: 3.2011.0.0
  Copyright c Schlumberger 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with plug-in installer for Petrel 2012 version. I used wix installer instead and everything is working fine.